# Slim v4, addErrorMiddleware doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: php, error-handling, slim, slim-4

So I just started using the slim PHP Framework and I'm a bit confused.
As stated in the documentation:
https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/middleware/error-handling.html#adding-custom-error-handlers

This should add some sort of Error Handling.

So I tested that code:

```
<?php
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = AppFactory::create();

// Add Routing Middleware
$app->addRoutingMiddleware();

// Define Custom Error Handler
$customErrorHandler = function (
    Request $request,
    Throwable $exception,
    bool $displayErrorDetails,
    bool $logErrors,
    bool $logErrorDetails,
    ?LoggerInterface $logger = null
) use ($app) {
    $logger->error($exception->getMessage());

    $payload = ['error' => $exception->getMessage()];

    $response = $app->getResponseFactory()->createResponse();
    $response->getBody()->write(
        json_encode($payload, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
    );

    return $response;
};

// Add Error Middleware
$errorMiddleware = $app->addErrorMiddleware(true, true, true);
$errorMiddleware->setDefaultErrorHandler($customErrorHandler);


$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
    $test = [];
    $foo = $test['nada'];
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello world!");
    return $response;
});

$app->run();
```

Now when I either call an undefined Route such as

```
localhost:8000/this/route/doenst/exist
```

or just simply let some faulty code run (accessing an undefined key from array)

```
localhost:8000/
```

I just get the "plain" Error

For undefined routes:
[image: undefindedRoutes]

For Coding Errors:
[image: codingError]

**So I guess my question is**:
How can i implement an error Handler that handles coding errors or calling to undefined routes?

Comment: Do you need the custom error handler?  What if you just had `$errorMiddleware = $app->addErrorMiddleware(true, true, true);`?

Comment: @NigelRen Yeah tried that first, also didnt do anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ErrorMiddleware` handles any type of `Exception` or `Throwable`.

You can test the ErrorMiddleware by throwing an Exception as follows:

```php
throw new \RuntimeException('Test error message');
```

Besides `Throwable` PHP has its older error level system of [warnings, notices and errors](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.error-reporting.php).

`Undefined index in index.php line 42` is just an PHP notice.

The Slim ErrorMiddleware does not handle this type of PHP errors.

To “catch” this type of PHP error, you can add a custom error handler using the `set_error_handler` function or you may add the Symfony [ErrorHandler component](https://github.com/symfony/error-handler), which provides tools for managing this kind of errors.

```
composer require symfony/error-handler
```

Add a custom middleware:

```php
// Throw an exception when a PHP error occurs
// and handled it with the Slim error handler.
ErrorHandler::register();

return $handler->handle($request);
```

Read more

- [PHP Error Handling and Logging](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php)
- [Predefined Constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php)

Comment: okey thank you, but then what does this default errorHandlingMiddleware handle?
Errors you throw?

Comment: I updated my answer. The ErrorMiddleware handles only Exceptions and Throwables. See [documentation](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/middleware/error-handling.html#adding-custom-error-handlers)

Comment: Did this answer help?

Comment: I'm still implementing a version which handles all the errors i want including 404

Comment: You can find mire information here: [Slim 4 - Error handling](https://odan.github.io/2020/05/27/slim4-error-handling.html)

Comment: First 'read more' link is now unavailable.